# How to see resources provisioned by others in an AWS OU if you're the root owner

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I have been invited by an account owner (owns AWS root account) into an organization and I have provisioned some EC2 instances. The account owner cannot see any of the EC2 instances I created or anything else I do in the AWS organization I was invited to. Is he supposed to create another login for himself in that OU and use that to login to see everything created in that OU by other members?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is described in this tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html#orgs_manage_accounts_access-cross-account-role